# AWS PowerShell EventBridge assembly model not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-event-bridge, aws-powershell

Error:

> New-Object : Cannot find type [PutEventsRequestEntry]: verify that the
> assembly containing this type is loaded

Code:

```
$entry = New-Object -Type Amazon.EventBridge.Model.PutEventsRequestEntry

$entry.Detail = $detailObject
$entry.Source = "inbound"
$entry.DetailType = "record sent"
$entry.Time = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"

Write-EVBEvent -Entry $events -Select "*"
```

I have AWS.Tools.Common and AWS.Tools.EventBridge modules installed via this command:

```
Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.EventBridge
```

And I can see them listed with this command:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

This code was originally working, I'm not sure what has changed. It's on a WorkSpaces instance though, so anything might have happened.

Do I need to Install the AWS SDK as well?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EventBridge/TPutEventsRequestEntry.html

I tried to install like this:

```
Install-Package AWSSDK.EventBridge -Version 3.7.5.29
```

> No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name
> 'AWSSDK.EventBridge'

I tried installing the assembly like this:

Download SDK from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-obtain-assemblies.html

Move the AWSSDK.EventBridge.dll and AWSSDK.Core.dll files to the script root, and unblock the file in properties.

Load the library:

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath "./AWSSDK.Core.dll"
Add-Type -LiteralPath "./AWSSDK.EventBridge.dll"
```

But I still get the same error related to the PutEventsRequestEntry object.

Edit:
I removed all associated libraries, and reinstalled using this command:

```
Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Installer
Install-AWSToolsModule -Name EventBridge -CleanUp
```

No change though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with AWS PowerShell tools and PowerShell 5, with no clear resolution, other than upgrading to PowerShell 7, or continually reinstalling until it works...

> The issue self-resolves by itself after multiple retries to install a
> module.

Even under PS7 I still had issues, and need to run this command also:

```
Import-Module AWS.Tools.EventBridge
```

Some details here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell/issues/273